# cURL returns JSON data

Tags: json, http, curl

When typing the following cURL into cmd prompt, "**curl [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts**"](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts**%22),
it returns an array of JSON data. (online rest api)

I have been given a command, "**curl -u recruiter:supersecret localhost:3000/raw**". When typed in the command should return json data.

Using json-server I was able to create a json file and host it locally. When typing the url it created, it displayed the JSON data.

**How can I use that specific command to return json data?**

Can anyone please provide some direction on how to go about doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what your question is or what you're asking. If you're curling for /raw, the json file you're hosting with json-server should have a `raw` field like:

```
{ "raw": "some test data" }
```

read the getting started section for json-server:
https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Okay so what does the " -u recruiter:supersecret " represent ?

Comment: That's the username:password for basic authentication.  In this case you don't need that because as a test server it works regardless.

Comment: Okay cool, I will try that out now. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Besides the confusion about the username and password, I got it to work. I created a JSON array and created the /raw field and added my data. Another issue was the default port was not set to :3000.